# Retrieve display value of combobox winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I set the `DisplayMemberPath` of a `comboBox` as well as the `ItemsSource`, now i'm trying to retrieve the `selectedText` that is displayed but there is no `selectedText` property. I tried

```
string s = comboBoxItem.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

but i'm getting a weird value. How do I retrieve the Displayed value of the comboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `comboBox1`, in C# winforms, you can get the selected value with `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`. In WPF (what apparently you want), you can get this information directly from the `Content` property; you can access it by doing:

```
ComboBoxItem curItem = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
string selectedValue = curItem.Content.ToString();
```

Comment: I just cast the comboBox.selectedItem to the datatype instead of to ComboBoxItem. Thanks

Comment: Sure, this is exactly the same: .SelectedItem is defined as an Object (to be honest, not sure why) and thus has to be casted before accessing its properties.