# How do I get the text, not the name of the comboboxitem, from a combobox with C# in Windows Runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I read many other questions about this and the answers don't work for me. How can I get the text content of a combobox in C#? This is a Windows Store app, not WPF, nor Silverlight.

```
<ComboBox Name="ColorListSortSelection" Grid.Column="1" Margin="24,5,24,8"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By HSB</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By SBH</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By BHS</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By HBS</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By SHB</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By BSH</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Sort By Name</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

and the C# code to go with it:

```
object Temp = ColorListSortSelection.SelectedItem;
string Content = Temp.ToString();
```

The Content string ends up being "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem", not the string that appears in the box.

The .Content member is private, so I can't access the text that way.

I'm sure that I just did something wrong here, but the solution eludes me.

Dave

Comment: `Content` is not private. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content

Comment: Oh, no no no.  You're doing it wrong.  Everything.  And you're only going to cause yourself heartbreak if you continue down this path.  You need to research MVVM in WPF/Windows store apps.  Stop before you waste too much time manipulating your UI via the codebehind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve display value of combobox winrt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628869/retrieve-display-value-of-combobox-winrt)

Comment: Will, thanks. It's hard to break old habits learned from years of C++ and MFC all while meeting unrealistic deadlines. Still, it's not technically wrong, just different. I just posted another question about binding problems I'm having, showing that even MVVM type stuff is not as easy as it should be. Maybe you can look it up and answer it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for an answer for an hour before asking the question. As usual, the answer presented itself only a moment later:

```
<x:String>Sort By HSB</x:String>
```

The items should not be ComboBox items, they should be strings.

If anyone wants to comment and let me know more about the "x:" and why that works, the info would be appreciated. is that just a way for the XAML to access OS or language features?

Thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the selected item's value by doing this

```
StrExample = cmbTypeInstallation.SelectionBoxItem.ToString()
```

The `SelectionBoxItem` gives you the value of the selected item when the combobox is closed

I think this would work even without having the `X:` in your *XAML*